# Show last 5 submitted data using only JS and HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a small question,
I am yet a beginner with Java Script and I don't have that much of knowledge with it. My question is:

I need to create a fake donation form. The form contains fields where the user can write his data like his phone number, donate amount etc... and when the user hit submit his donate amount and his name should be shown in a table, besides the last other 4 donations of the other people. I think that my code should look like that

```
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <form action="#" name="myForm" id="myForm">

            <br>name: <input type="text" name="name" id="donatorName"></br>
            <span id="Enter your name"></span>

            <br>Donate amount: <input type="number" name="donateAmount" id="amount"></br>
            <span id="Your total donate amount"></span>
            <br/>

            <button type="button" value="submit" onclick="return validation(); document.getElementById('container').style.display='none'">submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div id="new_container">
        <p id="displa_name"></p>
        <p id="display_total_amount"></p>

        <div id="Btn"></div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        function validation(){
            var donatorName = document.getElementById("donatorName").value;
            var donateAmount = document.getElementById("amount").value;

            // donatorName validation
            if(donatorName == ""){
                document.getElementById("donatorName").innerHTML = "Name cannot be empty";
                document.getElementById("donatorName").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }

            // donateAmount validation
            if(donateAmount == ""){
                document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = "Total amount cannot be empty";
                document.getElementById("amount").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }
            if(donateAmount < 1){
                document.getElementById("amount").innerHTML = "Donate amount should be greater than 0";
                document.getElementById("amount").style.color = "#ff0000";
                return false;
            }
            showDetails();
        }
    
        function showDetails(){
            document.getElementById('container').style.display='none';
            // name
            const  = document.getElementById("amount").value;
            document.getElementById("display_name").innerHTML = `DonatorName: ${donatorName}`;    
            document.getElementById("display_total_amount").innerHTML = `TotalAmount: ${donateAmount}`;    
    
</script>

</body>
```

I am not sure about my code, so please help me and explain to me how else I can do it. I want to keep it simple for now so please give me some advices :D

Comment: It's a fake form so where are the other donations that it is meant to list coming from? That data must be stored somewhere beforehand. If by "fake" you mean there is no actual donations happening but you still want to catalogue the previous "fake" entries you will need to store the data somewhere server-side in some way. Can be as simple as a text file, although I would recommend a json file for readability and ease of accessing the data.

Comment: Welcome to SO!  Is this a form that is generally working and you are just looking for feedback?  If so, then you should ask this at [the Code Review Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead of here.  Is this code that is not working for some reason and you want to know why?  Then make sure you include a [mcve], steps to reproduce, actual and expected behavior, and any error messages you may be seeing.  Also, FYI, I see a line `const = document.getElementById("amount").value;` which is invalid syntax.  Good luck, and happy coding!

Comment: @Aurange You've described what I actually want, and rhemmuuu described it even more. I want that the user write his name and amount and then it will be shown as if he has done a real donation and then it should be listed in the HTML with the las 5 previous donations. The data could be temporarily stored in arrays

Comment: @AlexanderNied Thank you mate! I am really happy that I get some help by you and that I could with my few experience help others. The code that I wrote doesn't work probably and this is because I don't know how to make it works, because I need to use JS with it and I am yet a beginner with JS so I thought that maybe an experienced programmer could help me with it and explain it a little bit :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you use backend language for this, like PHP, but if javaScript is what you needed, here's a simple way for that.
You can store the data in an array, or cache them so that the data will not be lost even when tab is refreshed.
But let's use array for this example. You already have your form so let's skip it.

For the table in HTML:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="displayDonations">
        <!-- Data will be displayed here thru javaScript -->
    </tbody>
</table>
```

javaScript:

```
let donations = [];

function validation() { // This is called when you submit the form
    // Put your validations here
    // Example Validation: return false if not valid
    if (!isValid()) return false; 

    // Remove first element of the array if length == 5
    if (donations.length == 5) {
        donations.shift();
    }

    // Push object into the donations array
    donations.push(
        {
            "name"   : document.getElementById("donatorName").value,
            "amount" : document.getElementById("amount").value
        }
    );

    showDetails();
}

function showDetails() {
    let tableBody = "";

    donations.forEach((element) =>{
        // Construct what you want to display
        tableBody += ""
            + "<tr>"
            +   "<td>" + element.name + "</td>"
            +   "<td>" + element.amount + "</td>"
            + "</tr>"
        ;
    });
    
    // Write the tableBody to the HTML
    document.getElementById("displayDonations").innerHTML = tableBody;
}
```

Comment: Thank you friend! this is exactly what I am looking for, but It doesn't show the submitted info yet, and I think that this problem show because of this error  Uncaught ReferenceError: isValid is not defined
 Thanks again for your help :D I will try to find a way to fix this problem.

Comment: Yes, isValid() is just an example validation, you  have to replace it with your own validation. Sorry it was not clear..

Comment: I have noticed that, you also left a comment that I firstly didn't noticed. Really thank to you I solved my problem and I understand how I will make it work for the next time

Comment: Sorry but I have one last question: How can I show only the last 5 inputs? and delete all previous ones?

Comment: I edited the answer and added a condition to remove the first element of the array if its length is already 5 by using [shift()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)